# How to save console output to a txt file and then display it on the screen right after?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am kind of confused about how I would write console output to a txt file and then display it right after. Any help would be appreciated. This is the code I used so far:

```
public static void savedata(){
    try {
        PrintStream myconsole = new PrintStream(new File("Result.txt"));
        System.setOut(myconsole);
        myconsole.print(generateReport());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
public static void displaydata(){
    File file = new File("Result.txt");
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()){
            String num = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's not working with this code?

Comment: The console output doesnt show anymore and nothing pops up.

Comment: What is `myconsole.print(generateReport());` supposed to do? How are you calling `savedata()` and `displaydata()`?

Comment: What do you expect as output? You will run into an infinite loop that fills `Result.txt` _if_ `generateReport()` returns more than one line of text -- assuming you're calling `savedata()` and then `displaydata()`, because in `displaydata()` you're reading from and writing to *the same file within a loop*.

Comment: I expect to see generatereport() being displayed within that text file that pops up on the screen. I just dont know how to do that/

Comment: What screen do you mean? Can you share more code?